# отключить рекламный плагин AddMob за деньги

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, google-play, admob

В андроид-игру, сделанную на *Unity3d* встроена реклама посредством плагина *AdMob*. Плагин - набор скриптов, отключить которые можно сняв галочку с чек-бокса скрипта. Можно сделать кнопку "отключить рекламу" и по клику по ней отключать плагин.

Правильно ли так делать? И, собственно, сам вопрос: как это нажатие сделать платным?

Answer (score 1):

Монетизация в многих играх осуществляется, как раз таким способом - отключение рекламы. Так делать правильно. 
Чтобы "сделать нажатие платным", Вам нужно подключить Google API для покупок "in app purchase" (если Вы собираетесь выкладывать в Google Play). На кнопку ставить обработчик, который запускает покупку. Попробуйте поискать в "Andorid Unity3d In App Purchase Tutorial". Вставил бы ссылки, но не могу)